# What is the best way to sign out and sign back into google in an iOS app?

Tags: swift, xcode, authentication

I am currently signing my user out like this:

```
 print(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser != nil) // true - signed in
 GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signOut()
 print(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser != nil) // false - signed out
```

Here is my is My AppDelegate

```
 class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {



func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    // Intializing Google Sign In...
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = []
        
        
        
//        FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID = "674329356626-ev6hn62oiqcj0o228nt85vv2bgroa45j.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
  -> Bool {
  return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

    if error != nil{

        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: user.authentication.idToken, accessToken: user.authentication.accessToken)

    // Logging to Firebase...
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (res, err) in

        if err != nil{

            print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        }
        // User Logged In Successfully...
        // Sending Notification To UI...
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("SIGNIN"), object: nil)
        // Printing Email ID
        print(res?.user.email)
    }

    // Check for sign in error
            if let error = error {
                if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.hasNoAuthInKeychain.rawValue {
                    print("The user has not signed in before or they have since signed out.")
                } else {
                    print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                return
            }

            // Post notification after user successfully sign in
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .signInGoogleCompleted, object: nil)
}



// MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    // Called when a new scene session is being created.
    // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
    return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
    // Called when the user discards a scene session.
    // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
    // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
}

}
```

Sign in code:

```
 GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
```

Once the user is signed in, what is the best way for me to sign them out and prompt for them to sign in again?  Please note that I am using the GoogleSignIn api.

Also note that I setup my google sign in functionality from here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start?ver=swift

What seems to be happening in my app is the when my sign out function executes the current user is set to nil.  However, when the user is signed out I can still access the data from the signed out user.  I want the user to be able to sign out of their current account and sign into a new account for which I can access data from their newly signed in account.

My app should not retain data from the previous logged out user.

Comment: I don't use this 3rd party login, but - why are you retaining any data on sign out? Is this an issue with the API or your app? Seems to me like your app should **fully** logout someone internally. (And if you think it does? Post more code. Thanks.)

Comment: Thanks.  I agree that my app should not be retaining any of the previous user's data after logged out. Please see the updated code above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signOut()

I also setup my google sign with firebase which seemed to help